Boolean modifier is ignoring original object of array
I am trying to make this pattern of holes on my object

I made the 4 cylinders through an array with the left most one being the original. When I apply the Boolean and turn of the cylinders there is no hole made from the original

I am pretty stumped anyone got a solution?
Edit:
Tried switching solved to fast just did this


Try applying the filter

Have you tried setting the Solver to Fast instead of Exact?

Yes I have. instead of making a hole it just merges the the first cylinder into it completely

Ok I found out what was wrong there was a face behind the first object that I used as a reference. It interfered with the Boolean but once deleted the problem went away.
